# Why do i have to reload page for javascript to work probably?

Tags: javascript

For some reason i have to reload my page for my javascript to work, or else it jumps into an `if` statement it should'nt, preventing it from running.

The problem happens at **//Create Div Posts**
The js should see the if **if(elem.width == 0)** as false, and jump to the `else` statement. 
It does so upon reloading the page.

I have checked - the element the `if` statement checks upon first load does have the correct image file attached to it, so why it considers it to be of the width == 0 until reloaded i cant figure out?

```
function postCreate(){

    // Image Array
    for (var i = 0; i < imgcount; i++) {
        imgArray[i] = new Image();
        imgArray[i].src = 'images/posters/ps' + i + '.jpg';
    }
    imgArray.reverse();
    // Magic Section
    postDel(function(){
        div = document.createElement('div');
        for (var i = 0; i < (imgscreen - 1); i++){
            // Image
            var elem = document.createElement("img");
            console.log(elem);
            elem = imgArray[i + imggrow]

            //Text
            var posttxt = [
                "type: " + genre[1] +"<br>title: vægge af beton<br>director: nicolai haugaard<br>role: sound designer & sound recordist", 
                "type: webseries<br>title: flush<br>director: anna nørskov<br>role: sound designer",
                "type: shortfilm<br>title: clay<br>director: leonard rääf<br>role: sound designer",
                "type: feature film<br>title: en rapport om festen og gæsterne<br>director: søren peter langkjær<br>role: sound designer",
                "type: shortfilm<br>title: sigøjnerjagt<br>director: mikkel andreas smidt<br>role: rerecording mixer",
                "type: feature film<br>title: den tid på året<br>director: paprika steen<br>role: sound design doing internship at nordisk film",
                "type: feature film<br>title: ternet ninja<br>director: anders matthesen<br>role: sound design doing internship at nordisk film",
                "type: feature film<br>title: før frosten<br>director: michael noer<br>role: dialog edit doing internship at nordisk film",
                "type: feature film<br>title: far til fire i solen<br>director: Martin Miehe-Renard<br>role: sound design doing internship at nordisk film",
                "type: feature film<br>title: lykke-per<br>director: Bille August<br>role: sound design doing internship at nordisk film",
                "type: shortfilm<br>title: hvad hvis alle farver var blå<br>director: hannah elbke<br>role: sound designer",
                "type: shortfilm<br>title: why woman<br>director: sebastian bjerregaard<br>role: sound designer",
                "type: shortfilm<br>title: soler sig<br>director: sigurd bleken<br>role: sound designer",
                "type: shortfilm<br>title: slushice<br>director: søren grinderslev<br>role: sound designer",
                "type: shortfilm<br>title: kong vincent<br>director: mikkel smidt<br>role: sound designer & sound recordist",
                "type: shortfilm<br>title: guldalder<br>director: mikkel smidt<br>role: sound designer"
            ]
            //Create Div Posts
            if(elem.width == 0){
                return null;
            } else {
                imgcurrent = i + imggrow + 1;
                // div
                clone = div.cloneNode();
                clone.setAttribute("class", "poster-img");
                clone.setAttribute("id", "postnr" + i)
                posterList.appendChild(clone);
                // <p> element
                var elemtxt = document.createElement('p');
                elemtxt.innerHTML = posttxt[i + imggrow];
                elemtxt.setAttribute("class", "postinfo");

                elemId = document.getElementById("postnr" + i); 
                elemId.appendChild(elem);
                elemId.appendChild(elemtxt);
                // Animation
                elem.animate([
                    { opacity: 0 }, 
                    { opacity: 1 }
                ], 
                    { duration: 1000, }
                );
            }
        }
    });
}

//-------- Delete Previous Divs ---------------//
  function postDel(_callback){
    posterList.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(n => n.remove());
    _callback();
  }
```

Comment: I think the width of the `img` tag, if not forced, will be set its dimensions when the image is loaded. that being said you might wanna listen to the `onLoad` method of each `img` element before you can do anything with it

Comment: could you elaborate? Where in the code should i do an `onLoad` function for each `img`?

Comment: like after you instantiate an  `Image()` to can attach an event listener onload to it.